# Ubuntu 12.04 not remembering settings

Tags: 12.04, settings

Ubuntu cannot remember many settings I have set. For example, when I customize the keyboard layout, it does not remember it after restart. Nor does it remember which programs that I have locked onto the launcher. Is there a fix to this? (It does however remember which wallpaper I wanted to use)

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS